# React useState does update in dev tools but not in the console

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Hey i have this function

```
   const [mouseIsDown, setMouseDown] = useState(true);

   function handleMouseUp() {
        console.log('mouseUp')
        console.log(mouseIsDown)
        setMouseDown(false);
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(mouseIsDown)
        }, 1000)

    }
```

and when it is trigged it logs:

```
- mouseUp
- true
- true
- true
- true
- true
...
```

But the react dev tools show that mouseIsDown is actually false, but when i log its value in a interval it still logs **true** when i set the value of **mouseIsDown** to **false**.

I have no idea why its like that, any help is welcome :D

Comment: `setMouseDown` doesn't actually change the value of `mouseIsDown`. It gets applied asynchronously and you won't see the change reflected until your component function gets invoked again and calls useState again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this line

```
setInterval(() => {
     console.log(mouseIsDown)
}, 1000)
```

when you use interval like that, the inside of the function is like a "snapshot" of current state. this is why you always get the starting `mouseIsDown` value.

in order to fix this, you need to use `useRef` as a reference value, so this will save the current state inside of the interval.

new code:

```
const [mouseIsDown, setMouseDown] = useState(true);
const mouseIsDownRef = useRef();
mouseIsDownRef.current = mouseIsDown; //this will set the current value

function handleMouseUp() {
        console.log('mouseUp')
        console.log(mouseIsDown)
        setMouseDown(false);
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(mouseIsDownRef?.current)
        }, 1000)

    }
```

Comment: This works :D, but may i ask what the ? does in ```console.log(mouseIsDownRef**?**```

Comment: great :) -- it is a short for this -> `imouseIsDownRef.current ? imouseIsDownRef.current : null`